# PHP Design Patterns - Handling user permissions, removing PHP if statements

Tags: php, html, privileges

I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement user permissions on a website written in PHP. Currently, this is my strategy:

- A User class with an array of type PagePermissions
- A Page Permissions class with members of type ActionPermissions and a method 'checkAction' that returns a true/false if the action is allowed
- Each action permission is named and has a value of allowed, denied or undefined.

When a user is created/modified, their permissions are set. At login, the User object is loaded into $_SESSION. For each request, the appropriate PagePermissions object is loaded into a GLOBAL, then each view has:

```
<?php
include 'header.php'
?>
<!-- Some HTML code for the view -->
<!-- ... -->

<?php if($GLOBAL['pagePermissions']->checkAction('Admin-Only-Action')) { ?>
<a href="#adminAction">Admin-Only-Action</a>
<? } ?>

<!-- Some HTML code for the view -->
<!-- ... -->

<?php
include 'footer.php'
?>
```

I also have a controller behind each view, with similar logic to allow/deny the action if it is posted anyway.

**Is there a better approach, that would allow me to abstract the spaghetii PHP code from my (mostly) HTML views? Can I create PHP 'tags' that would render/not render based on user permissions? Is there some syntatic sugar that would make this cleaner?**

I can provide more details or code samples if needed.

Thanks

Comment: you can use a FRONT controller Pattern thing for this. This FRONT controller will be inherited by every controller and you can check the permission of every action just after the Dispatching is done in the FRONT controller itself.

Comment: Depending on the inherited project I receive, I will either make extensive use of includes or make extensive use of objects. For includes, I do something like: include 'everyone_menu.inc'; include 'admin_menu.inc'; include 'editor_menu.inc'; Then, I wrap the include in an "if" to control what it is included. With objects, I make a menu object. Inside that I have methods for each menu and a show_menu method that uses if statements to decide which menu to show.

Answer (score -1):

If it were me, I would do as follows:

1. Instead of playing around with globals, use a singleton pattern.  This means you don't have to put the object in the global namespace but instead get a shared instance from a module.
2. You could use exceptions and exception handling to require permissions and redirect to an error page.

So for example, your API might look more like

```
<?php
include 'Security.php';

my $secman = new Security();
$secman->require_permission('basic-user');
$can_admin = $secman->check_permissions('admin');

include 'header.php';
?>
<!-- Some HTML code for the view -->
<!-- ... -->

<?php if($can_admin) { ?>
<a href="#adminAction">Admin-Only-Action</a>
<? } ?>
```

I like to put my security checks at the top of the file, function, or whatever.